# Connect humidifier and furnace drains directly to pipe

Tags: plumbing, hvac

My furnace has a bypass humidifier and another pipe that drain to a little pump. This little pump activates periodically, pushing the water up to a drain pipe (which ends up going straight back down to the floor, then onto the normal drain lines).

Is there any reason I can't just change these two pipes to go directly to the drain line, removing the pump altogether? Obviously they need to slope downhill, but there's plenty of room for it.

Secondary question: if I do this, do I need a trap?

The red arrows point to the drain lines going down to the little pump. The blue arrow points to the line going from the pump the drain lines. You can just see where it is loosely held via insertion into the drain line by the top right of the water softener.

[image]

Comment: Your picture shows one condensate outlet above the level of the drain entrance, and one below it. If the drain itself goes below the lower outlet, you can dispense with the condensate pump. You need an air gap between the drain and the condensate pipes, and you ned a trap and a vent (which you **should have** in the current arrangement as well.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, thank you. The entrance of the drain pipe that is slightly visible above the softener goes straight down nearly the whole way to the floor. There is actually a trap in that line, but is obscured in this photo. For the vent - the top of the right most pipe is open. Is that sufficient? (If you want to make your comment an answer, I will gladly accept it.)

Comment: The tubing ID'd by the blue arrow is the _output_ from the pump? Where does it go?

Comment: It goes up slightly above the water softener, and the bends back down at 180 degrees to a drain pipe (which itself runs like an L - the entrance is very high, but the lower part is almost at the floor level.

Comment: It should work just fine, be sure it is vented. Your condensate pan is by the open end of the T and the humidifier by the gap around the pipe and tubing. I do not know of any restrictions on this but I also do not know your local code so you should check that to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that tee fitting at the lower red arrow? That's the condensate output from the furnace. Burning gas in the winter produces liquid condensate in the furnace exhaust pipe; the condensate drains back into the furnace and out through this point.

The burner condensate drain is the lowest of the three water sources shown here. If you can re-arrange the drain stack so that there's a trap below this elevation, then yes you can eliminate the pump and let the furnace, air conditioner, and humidifier all gravity-drain into it.

Allow several inches of height (at least!) from the water level in the trap to the top of the stand pipe where the three drains converge. The reason for this is that you wouldn't want any overflow. More height above the trap supports building a little more pressure, which supports pushing a little more flow through the trap.